# Missing Right Parenthesis

Tags: oracle11g

I am getting missing right parenthesis for below Oracle SQL

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OAS_HRMS_LEAVE_DETAIL WHERE(((trunc(TO_DATE('12/10/2014','mm  /dd/yyyy')) BETWEEN trunc(LEAVE_FROM_DATE) AND trunc(LEAVE_TO_DATE))OR(trunc(TO_DATE('12/11  /2014','mm/dd/yyyy')) BETWEEN(trunc(LEAVE_FROM_DATE) AND trunc(LEAVE_TO_DATE)))) AND    (EMPLOYEE_NO='US/Z/054' AND APPROVAL_STATUS IN ('Active','Approved')))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try removing the parenthesis around 2nd **Trunc(leave_from_date) AND    Trunc(leave_to_date)**

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   oas_hrms_leave_detail
WHERE (
(
    (Trunc(To_date('12/10/2014','mm  /dd/yyyy')) BETWEEN Trunc(leave_from_date) AND    Trunc(leave_to_date))
    OR
    (Trunc(To_date('12/11  /2014','mm/dd/yyyy')) BETWEEN Trunc(leave_from_date) AND    Trunc(leave_to_date))
)
    AND(employee_no='US/Z/054' AND    approval_status IN ('Active','Approved')))
```

Answer (score 0):

VERY HARD TO READ...and don't really know what conditions you are trying to do.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM OAS_HRMS_LEAVE_DETAIL 
WHERE(((trunc(TO_DATE('12/10/2014','mm/dd/yyyy')) 
BETWEEN trunc(LEAVE_FROM_DATE)AND trunc(LEAVE_TO_DATE)) 
OR (trunc(TO_DATE('12/11  /2014','mm/dd/yyyy')) 
BETWEEN(trunc(LEAVE_FROM_DATE) AND trunc(LEAVE_TO_DATE)))//)// <- one extra added here?
AND(EMPLOYEE_NO='US/Z/054' AND APPROVAL_STATUS IN ('Active','Approved')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't see any missing right parenthesis issue, but you do have a LOT of parentheses!  I would try to minimise their use - you do need them where there are ANDs and ORs, bit not everywhere.

Here is a simplified version:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OAS_HRMS_LEAVE_DETAIL 
WHERE
 (   DATE '2014-12-10' BETWEEN trunc(LEAVE_FROM_DATE) AND trunc(LEAVE_TO_DATE)
  OR DATE '2014-12-11' BETWEEN trunc(LEAVE_FROM_DATE) AND trunc(LEAVE_TO_DATE)
  )
AND EMPLOYEE_NO='US/Z/054' 
AND APPROVAL_STATUS IN ('Active','Approved')
```

Note:

1. Use of date literals e.g. DATE '2014-12-10' instead of a TO_DATE function call
2. No need to TRUNC() a literal date

Also, do you really need to truncate the LEAVE_FROM_DATE and LEAVE_TO_DATE?  If these are meant to be just dates (no time part) then they should be validated as such (e.g. check constraints) and then you can remove those TRUNCs too:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OAS_HRMS_LEAVE_DETAIL 
WHERE
 (   DATE '2014-12-10' BETWEEN LEAVE_FROM_DATE AND LEAVE_TO_DATE
  OR DATE '2014-12-11' BETWEEN LEAVE_FROM_DATE AND LEAVE_TO_DATE
  )
AND EMPLOYEE_NO='US/Z/054' 
AND APPROVAL_STATUS IN ('Active','Approved')
```